# Can't find the true url in a php project using Yii2

Tags: php, apache, web, yii2

I'm new in php coding and I'm using Yii2 framework
I'm trying to make a simple project as follow:
I added a .php file named "PostController.php" in the backend/controllers and I wrote this codes in this file:

```
<?php
namespace backend\controllers;
use yii\web\Controller;
class PostController extends Controller

{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }
}
?>
```

and I created a file in beckend/views named "post" and in this folder I created a.php file named index.php
then I just wrote one line in index.php for test as bellow:

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

Now I want to see this index file (Hello World) in my browser. Which url I should enter in my browser to see that? I tried the bellow url and it didn't worked!:

> projectname.loc/index.php?r=post/index

Comment: try  projectname.loc/backend/web/index.php?r=post/index

Comment: Error 404 is displayed :(

Comment: and with  your  url ? ..you get an error?

Comment: with this url you mean?:  http://projectname.loc/index.php?r=post/index
as i use this url the "Congratulations" page displays. (the same page when i write "projectname.loc" displays)

Comment: What is your ServerName and DocumentRoot in Apache2 host configuration for "backend" application? You start your project from yii2-advanced-app ?

Answer (score 0):

if pretty url is true then you have to access the controller like

```
localhost/projectname/backend/web/index.php/controller/action
```

if pretty url is false then you have to access the controller like

```
localhost/projectname/backend/web/index.php?r=controller/action
```

if you project is in your local machine, if its on your server then you have to write server name instead of localhost

Answer (score -1):

You should go to projectname.loc/post (or projectname.loc/post/index), to be in this action. before that you have to turn on the "prettyUrl" in your urlManager

If you use basic tamplate from yii2 your namespace must be app/backend/controllers and you should go to projectname.loc/index.php?r=backend/post/index

"backend" it will be a path to your controller, not a module